# Change tab title of "Integration" Tab in woocommerce admin panel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a custom plugin to add a woocommerce integration, however i am not sure how can i change the tab title from **Integration** to **Cutom title**,

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Care to mention what plugin you are using?

Comment: Its a Custom plugin I have writte

Comment: There is a plugin called [WooCommerce Custom Product Tabs Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-custom-product-tabs-lite/) that allows you to add a custom tab with a custom name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the name of the integration tab.  Multiple integrations are supposed to share the integration tab, so it wouldn't make sense to allow changing the name.

It is basically like the 'Shipping' or 'Checkout' tab, so third party integrations show up in a secondary menu.  You can see this behavior once there are 2+ integrations loaded.

You can set the name of your page in the secondary menu by setting the method_title property in your constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->method_title = 'Your plugin title';
}
```

Woocommerce explains when it's appropriate to use the integration tab vs a new tab in their [plugin guide](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/create-a-plugin/).

If you need to create an entirely new settings tab there is a guide here:

http://speakinginbytes.com/2014/07/woocommerce-settings-tab/